# How to install svelte, i seem to have issues with it

Tags: node.js, frameworks, svelte

So I am new to javascript frameworks, and I want to start using svelte. So I went to svelte website and start the installing process, and I am already getting errors. I will keep communicating if you have any questions about my problem. Here Is my terminal:

coolstuff@srimaans-air svelte % npx degit sveltejs/template svelte-demo

! could not fetch remote https://github.com/sveltejs/template

! could not find commit hash for HEAD

coolstuff@srimaans-air svelte %

Comment: If you have any questions about my question please ask.

Answer (score 2):

Before you begin i strongly suggest you to learn how to create development environment for frameworks. There are tools such as vite, webpack.

you can easily start with vite

```
npm create vite@latest
```

or you can go with the sveltekit which also using vite

```
npm create svelte@latest my-app
```

after you set, you able to edit configuration files (vite.config.js, svelte.config.js etc) to specify output options of the pages you made.

you can find much more in here https://vitejs.dev/guide/

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fetch the github page you might first have to install degit. You can do so with this command:

`npm install -g degit`

If npx isn't working you can run this:

`npm install -g npx`

Edit: if that didn't solve it, then it's probably that git isn't installed yet. Try what was posted here:
https://github.com/Rich-Harris/degit/issues/37

Install `git` and run the commands from the `git` terminal instead of the regular one.

Comment: From some people, I heard this was an old way, and I tried it, but it doesn't work, but thank you for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Javascript frameworks require pre-requisites like node.js installed on your system.

Install node.js https://nodejs.org/en and after installing check by the below command if node.js is installed on your system properly.

```
$ node --version
```

After that you can use npm to install svelte app.
Refer this link here to figure out how to install a svelte app.
https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-for-new-developers